# Tracker afterFlush error with Meteor and Hammer JS package

Tags: javascript, meteor, hammer.js

I'm trying to use the hammer:hammer 2.0.4_2 package with Meteor 1.0.1 and I'm getting the following error:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a
>   function TypeError: undefined is not a function

I figured that the error has something to do with DOM not being rendered yet, because of the Helper Block. So far I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere. Does someone else have the same error or knows how this can be fixed?

---

client/profile.js

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {

    this.$('body').hammer({          <-- Line of the Error in Console..
         drag_min_distance:1,
         swipe_velocity:0.1
    })
 }

Template.myTemplate.events({
    'press #mcPress': function() {
        console.log('yay!')
    }
})
```

---

client/profile.html

```
{{#with thisUser}}

    // some html stuff

    <div id="mcPress">Some content</div>

{{/with}}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hammer.js as a stand-alone (which is how the official package is provided) **does not** ship with the [jQuery plugin](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/), so you can't use that syntax without manually adding the jQuery plugin yourself.

It's pretty easy to do your own local fork of that package and bolt the plugin on (I haven't released this yet as I'm quite sensitive about the Atmosphere namespace mess problem).  Alternatively, you could just include the plugin on page load.  Either way, that syntax should work or, failing that, you just have to use the non-jQuery syntax described in the [core docs](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/).

Comment: Ahh I didn't see that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: On top of what @richsilv mentioned, there's actually a bug in the packaged hammer:hammer 2.0.4_2 release (Nov 29th) that's causing even the non-JQuery syntax to give you this error. You can use the 2.0.4_1 release instead: `meteor add hammer:hammer@=2.0.4_1` and it will work (at least for non-JQuery)

Comment: @richsilv It's been a while but could you give a quick example for how the non-jQuery syntax would work with Meteor `Template.myTemplate.events({})` syntax?